# Will the WWE region RUU version work for my region?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, stock-android, htc-desire-s

The HTC Desire S RUU for Android 4.0 is now available in the HTCdev website ([htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads](http://htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads)).

Unfortunately (or is it?), region is set to (WWE - World Wide English)

My region is "038 - HTC India"

Will the WWE be compatible with my device or do I have to wait for a separate release for my region ?

I read somewhere that

> WWE - World Wide English, this tells us it is meant for devices all
>   over the world and is a generic update.

Is this true?

Comment: I have a question.
While installing HTC Deisre S ICS RUU was your bootloader status UNLOCK or LOCK?
Please also tell if you had S - ON or S - OFF.
Thanks.

Comment: My bootloader status was locked. and it was S-OFF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is true. It also removes all the crap the carriers put on there as well.